# Is webpack package included in my final react bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I am working on a legacy project which has a huge bundle size(>10MB).To analyze the packages and bundle size I have installed `danvk/source-map-explorer` tool.

Upon running the tool it is showing Webpack 15.76MB in the output(screenshot attached).

is this normal ?

[image]

Comment: That `webpack:///` is a protocol, not a package. Try this package for a better visualization: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 1):

No, webpack is used to create the handle and shouldn't be included after bundling.